# Pigeonholing a theory with union-closed sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, pigeonhole-principle

Here is a lemma I deduced that describes a possible proof technique but I'm not sure what to prove with it.

If $F$ is a finite set of formulas, say $F$ *distinguishes* a finite set of theories $S$ if $\vert \{ T \cap F : T \in S \} \vert = \vert S \vert$.

Lemma: Suppose $S$ is a finite union-closed set of theories of odd cardinality and $A$ and $B$ are finite sets of formulas both distinguishing $S$.  Then conditional on the union-closed sets conjecture, there exists $a \in A$, $b \in B$, and $T \in S$ such that $a \land b \in T$.

Corollary: if the members of $S$ are consistent extensions of $\text{ZFC}$, then there exists $a \in A$, $b \in B$ such that $\neg (a \land b)$ is not provable in $\text{ZFC}$.

The idea is that we have some consistent theories and by the union-closed sets conjecture more than half of them prove $a$ and more than half of them prove $b$, so at least one of them proves $a \land b$ but we don't know which.  However, since they're all consistent extensions of $\text{ZFC}$, we know $\text{ZFC}$ can't prove $\neg(a \land b)$.

Is the above clear and correct?

Are there any undecidability results that can be proved with this method?  Or anything at all interesting enough to justify calling it a "method" in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument seems fine - but I don't think you need to use any open conjecture for this! If $T$ contains $a$ and $T'$ contains $b$, then just by the fact that the set of theories is union-closed, $T\cup T'$ contains $a$ and $b$, so it proves $a \land b$, so this sentence is consistent with ZFC. Right?

Unfortunately, I think the setup you have in mind is kind of trivial, since if you have a union-closed set of theories, then they are all consistent with ZFC if and only if the single theory which is the union of all of them is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: Thanks, I see now why the conjecture isn't really being used.

Comment: I think this corollary is less trivial: if the union-closed sets conjecture fails on an odd-sized set, then there is a union-closed set of theories $S$ extending $\text{ZFC}$ distinguished by two sets of statements $A$ and $B$ with the property that for any $a \in A, b \in B$ there is a $T \in S$ that can't prove $a$ and it can't prove $b$.

Comment: @DanBrumleve be careful about the distinction between "contains" and "proves".

Comment: I don't think I know what that distinction is.  (I understand it's awkward for example to say an inconsistent theory "proves" something but I would think that means the same thing as "contains" anyway?).  I am assuming at least that they are logically closed so they are theories not just sets.  Writing $a \notin T \land b \notin T$ in my last comment would have been clearer though.

Comment: @DanBrumleve There are two common conventions when talking about theories. The first is that a theory is just a set of sentences. But then it's possible for a theory $T$ to prove a sentence $\varphi$ that it does not contain. Alternatively, you could identify a theory with its closure under probability (it sounds like you're doing this). But then it's hard to have a "union-closed" set of theories, since usually the union of two theories won't be closed!

Comment: In any case, you can always achieve the situation in your less trivial trivial corollary by adding ZFC to your collection of theories and making sure that none of the sentences in $A$ and $B$ are already provable in ZFC (otherwise they wouldn't be helping to distinguish the theories).

Comment: I accidentally wrote "probability" instead of "provability" above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue that we don't get a union-closed set of theories automatically.  My idea with the other corollary was that $\text{ZFC} \notin S$, so we'd be showing that $a \notin T \land b \notin T$ for some other theory.  But I'll have to rethink these definitions with your comments in mind.